# Why can't I use querystrings in my router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use the url path with the query string in the router as shown below.

```js
//App.js
          <Route
            path={"/my_account"}
            component={Pages.account}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path={"/support_main/notice?page=1"} Lik this!!!!!!!!!
            component={Pages.support_notice_list}
          />

// link.js
                  <Link to={"/support_main/notice?page=1"} className="menu-list-link">
                    <ListItemText
                      primary={item.text}
                      className="munu-list-text"
                    />
```

In this case, the page cannot be found.....:(

```js
//App.js
          <Route
            exact
            path={"/support_main/notice"} OK
            component={Pages.support_notice_list}
          />

// link.js
                  <Link to={"/support_main/notice?page=1"} className="menu-list-link">
                    <ListItemText
                      primary={item.text}
                      className="munu-list-text"
                    />
```

In the above case, it works normally.
Is there any way to use query string in router ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it's because RRDv5 deals only in matching the path, not any part of the query search string.

For route path matching, only the `"/support_main/notice"` is considered. To make this a bit more clear, here is a more conventional way to link to `"/support_main/notice"` and pass a search string. Here the path and search string are split up and explicitly passed.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/support_main/notice",
    search: "?page=1"
  }}
>
  To notice
</Link>
```

When you link to `"/support_main/notice?page=1"` the search isn't part of the path matching.

[Link to-object](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)

**to: object**

> An object that can have any of the following properties:
>
> - pathname: A string representing the path to link to.
> - search: A string representation of query parameters.
> - hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
> - state: State to persist to the location.
>
>   ```
>   <Link
>     to={{
>       pathname: "/courses",
>       search: "?sort=name",
>       hash: "#the-hash",
>       state: { fromDashboard: true }
>     }}
>   />
>   ```

Consider the following code:

```
const Page1MatchPath = () => <h1>Page 1 matched by path</h1>;
const Page1MatchPathAndQuery = () => <h1>Page 1 matched by path and query</h1>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/support_main/notice?page=1">To notice (string)</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/support_main/notice",
                search: "?page=1"
              }}
            >
              To notice (object)
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route
            path={"/support_main/notice?page=1"}
            component={Page1MatchPathAndQuery}
          />
          <Route path={"/support_main/notice"} component={Page1MatchPath} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit why-cant-i-use-querystrings-in-my-router]

Note that ***even though*** the full path and query string is listed ***first*** in the `Switch` that is doesn't match, and is skipped over and matched by path alone. In other words, it's *too* specific to match `"/support_main/notice"`, and yet doesn't take the query string into consideration for matching.

#### But why don't query strings work in `path` prop?

This is very likely due to the way path matching is handled. Under-the-hood RRDv5 `path` props are strings that [path-to-regex@^1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) understands. In this specific case the "?" character is interpreted as an [optional parameter](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#optional).

[Optional](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#optional)

> Parameters can be suffixed with a question mark (`?`) to make the
> parameter optional. This will also make the prefix optional.
>
> ```
> var re = pathToRegexp('/:foo/:bar?', keys)
> // keys = [{ name: 'foo', ... }, { name: 'bar', delimiter: '/', optional: true, repeat: false }]
>
> re.exec('/test')
> //=> ['/test', 'test', undefined]
>
> re.exec('/test/route')
> //=> ['/test', 'test', 'route']
> ```

To also more firmly put it, the [Usage](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#usage) outright also states in a note:

> **Please note:** The `RegExp` returned by `path-to-regexp` is intended for use with pathnames or hostnames. It can not handle the query
> strings or fragments of a URL.